# Three js Opaque mirror

Tags: three.js, webgl

I've implemented a mirror using the technique demonstrated here:
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html

I would like to make my reflection slightly opaque, so that things 'deeper' into the reflection appear darker.  I'm thinking to hijack the fragment shader, but not sure what's the best property to use to create this relationship.

Currently my mirror fragment shader:

```
vec4 color = texture2DProj(mirrorSampler, mirrorCoord);
color = vec4(blendOverlay(mirrorColor.r, color.r), blendOverlay(mirrorColor.g, color.g), blendOverlay(mirrorColor.b, color.b), 1.0);
vec3 outgoingLight = color.rgb;
${THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_fragment" ]}
gl_FragColor = vec4(outgoingLight,1.0);
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a `Fog` to the scene, enable it for the mirror render and disable it for the scene render?

Comment: Thanks, I have used fog and some careful lighting to get the effect I am after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is not actually how mirrors work. However, just apply a dark fog to your initial pass.

You might, however, get the results you really want by skipping the fog and instead applying some function of the `dot(Normal,View)` -- aka "facing ratio" -- to the brightness of the reflection term. A common approximation to the Fresnel equations, the "Schlick approximation," is `(pow((1.0-abs(dot(N,V))),5.0))` -- so that the reflection is simply stronger at grazing angles but dimmer at "deep" direct ones. This would be more like many real mirrors.

Comment: Thanks, fog did the job